# Using Lua to send custom values to a different program

Tags: input, lua, output

I'm new to Lua, so I have a simple question. I have a device and corresponding program that utilize Lua Scripts to interact with other programs. The scripts generally only do this through triggering key presses, but is is possible for me to just send normal integers to a program with a script... I mean, dumb question. *How* do I do this? Like, I get an output like "waveOut" from the device, and I want the second program to receive an input of "2"

Comment: Do your scripts accept input from standard input? Is your initial output the input your second script needs? You mention key presses how is that related here?

Comment: Ok, the device I mentioned is the Thalmic Labs Myo Armband. It reads EMG signals from your forearm, and can recognize five distinct gestures. The program that manages this is Myo Connect. The scripts take input from Connect in the form of these gestures, identified by terms such as "waveOut". The easiest example of this is the PowerPoint script. I can make a gesture, and it will go to the next slide. The functions that control that are as follows: 
'function forward()
    myo.keyboard("down_arrow", "press")
end'
I can then associate a certain gesture to call back this function and trigger it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added more info to the main question. My bad on that. A bit more info, we'll call the program I'm trying to interact with "#2," as it is still in development, and I'm not sure if I can talk about it freely. It works in a similar manner to Myo Connect, accepting data from an external device. Also as with Myo Connect, the data is already processed, and comes in a simplified form, but instead of being something like "waveOut", its just a basic number that is input to #2, ranging from "0-5" All I want to do is use the armband I have to replace the "0-5" inputs that #2 receives

Comment: I'm not clear what part of this you are trying to actually write and what lua has to do with this? Are you trying to convert the `waveOut` style input into numbers and send them to some other program? How does that second program accept input? How will the code you are going to write be run?

Comment: Myo Connect works like this: I have a collection of Lua scripts that M.C. is able to access. Based on which application is in the foreground, certain scripts will be made active over others by M.C. Using a script, I can have Myo Connect return whichever signals are being output by the armband. Based on which signals are being received, I can then make the script do certain things to interact with the active window. But this is generally used to simulate key presses. The second program accepts inputs the exact same way, from an external device, over a serial connection.

Comment: Then it sounds like you will need an application window that you can target and the lua script will then need to write to the appropriate serial connection (or socket) for that second application.

Comment: Alright, sounds doable enough. I was not quite sure, as I'm new to the programming scene, so thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Interprocess Communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

In Lua, you can use [io.popen](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-io.popen) to spawn a process with a pipe and send your integer as string to the target which checks `stdin` in intervals for new input.

An alternative would be a file to simulate this pipe.